# Is there anyway to "Intercept" an std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

Is there anyway to interrupt an std::thread while it's running, call a new method with it, have it return to where it was, and still have it be valid to use with the opengl context, windows etc that it has created?

Comment: only by having the thread itself polling some flag

Comment: Oh, that sucks. Thanks.

Comment: Apart from the 'call', sounds like a description of normal preemption.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a bit of an XY question. If instead of describing your proposed (and in this case flawed) solution X, why not describe the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: This is just something that I've thought would be very useful a lot in the past. It's not specific to any one problem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem